# /usr/local or /opt?

Tags: linux, fedora

How do you generally proceed for your package installations on Linux, for packages that are not part of your distrib's repos?

On my side I am used to install in /opt. But since, I saw this doc on the Internet: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/. Now I am confused: apparently /usr/local would be also a possibility.

What is the difference between both? Any best practices to share?

Thanks

SirFabel

Comment: Holy war territory *and* not really a programming topic to boot.

Comment: Similar question in [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34880/use-of-opt-and-usr-local-directories-in-the-context-of-a-pc), [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/122420/usr-local-or-opt), [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/what-is-the-difference-between-opt-and-usr-local)

Answer (score 44):

- Everything that has to be compiled & installed *Unix-style* and complies to FHS -> `/usr/local`
- Everything else (e.g. a java web-application that comes with it's own applicationserver and loads of resources in a zip archive -> `/opt`

Answer (score 25):

Just as additional interesting info: The original meaning of `/usr/local` is that if `/usr` is network-mounted (single `/usr` shared across multiple computers), `/usr/local` would be a separate filesystem local to the computer (partition on local disk).

And while on that topic, even if it's off-topic to the question: If there are multiple computers with different architectures, naturally there would be one `/usr` for each arch, but `/usr/share` would be yet another separate filesystem shared between architectures (hence 'share').

Comment: No... historically (yes, I was there!) /usr et al had the vendor-provided stuff, /usr/local was locally installed stuff (i.e., bash, gcc and other nice stuff).

Comment: @vonbrand Are you really contradicting the answer? It just sounds like whatever needs to be shared between host would be /usr, and whatever didn't need too, would be in /usr/local

Comment: @Didier A., when I started using Unix ('80es) there was *one* machine, no networking... and they had /usr and /usr/local.

Comment: @vonbrand Oh I see, interesting. Then it seems the original intent of having /usr and /usr/local is still a mystery.

Comment: @Didier A., again: /usr was what was shipped with the operating system, "standard" stuff, /usr/local was local additions (homebrewed, gotten off Usenet, filched from a friendly coleague at a convention, ...). Not standard, just common use.

Comment: @DidierA./@vonbrand - sounds like 80s use is the same as the 20s usage. no network involved.

Answer (score 8):

The way I do it is that if it requires a prefix to itself OR it's a binary package, I go for /opt (which is pretty much the Solaris way). If i'm compiling from source /usr/local is how I go.

Answer (score 6):

I put everything in a private directory and then use [GNU stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).

So, I'll install package X.ver to `/BASE/stow/X.ver`.  GNU stow will then combine all the packages (with symlinks) into `/BASE/bin`, `/BASE/lib`, etc.

Conflicts and removing packages are much easier to deal with.

Comment: I've typically used /usr/local/stow/<packagename> as the home for stow "packages", and feel like it's a good practice - if someone else looks in /usr/local it makes it obvious what's going on and what system is maintaining the symlinks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do interpret the FHS standard:

/usr/local is for locally built or locally installed files, whether packaged or not that somewhat become part of that instance of the Operating System.

/opt is a place to install "foreign" packages not part of the Operating System.

As long as you only use files on the single system where you build them, /usr/local is fine, and it is therefore the default base directory for the vast majority of open source software.

If you plan to redistribute your package, I would recommend using a custom base directory like /opt/myPackage.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris used /opt a lot. Many modern Linux distros now expect packages in /usr/local/.  The idea is the same - a place to put software that makes this machine do what it does, as opposed to the operating system.  It's roughly analogous to "Program Files" on a Windows system.

Pick one and stick to it.  It's easy enough to symlink /opt to /usr/local.

Comment: I like Lee's comment, nice way to think about the problem.  It would feel a bit weird to me to have an /opt on a Debian machine, but that's probably just personal preference.

Comment: Please don't. The FHS might be quite a bit dated, but it's reasoning on /usr vs/usr/local vs /opt is sound: Standard, distribution provided; locally installed, like homebrew or experimental stuff off github; vendor-provided non-standard stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you recompile a software provided by your operating system distribution, to leverage several architecture advantages specific to your very own machine, use /usr/local.

If you add a piece of software from other sources, than your operating system distribution, put it into /opt.