# Ubuntu Package (.deb) Recommendations Installation Folder and Binary Name

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packages, jar, deb

I'm building a .deb file for an executable jar I've built for myself. I got a .deb built and installed my program to `/usr/bin`.

As I have a jar I now had an executable file called `/usr/bin/mylovelyprogram.jar`. I noticed that no other files in the directory had an extension.

Now, I know that having an extension or not doesn't matter, but it did bother me since my program stood out. I wondered if it was usual to rename packaged executable `jars` such that they no longer have an extension? Or, if there was some other standard e.g. putting the jar somewhere else and using a symlink? I'd like to conform to existing standards where possible, mainly so I do not fall into bad habits if I ever decide to distribute my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" unix location for local packages (things that are specific to one computer, and not a whole network installation) is /usr/local

Many Linux distributions choose to break this standard and just dump everything in /usr, or (heaven forbid) /opt!  (don't you just hate it when some application decides to fill up your root partition because it's dumped itself in /opt which didn't exist before hand? mentioning no names, libreoffice...)

Your jar file is effectively a library, and should be in somewhere like /usr/local/lib/myapp/

You should have a small script in /usr/local/bin which calls your jar file using the java virtual machine.

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar /usr/local/lib/myapp/myjar.jar $*
```

And of course you should be sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH

This arrangement stops your software from getting mingled up with the operating system software, and also keeps it on a partition which should have plenty of room.  It also fits in nicely with non-Linux systems as well, which, as it's Java, you are fully expecting it to be running on, yes?  That is after all the whole point of Java, isn't it? Cross-platform?

Comment: I've rebuilt by .deb to install to /usr/local/lib/myapp/ - thanks for you advice. However, when I tested removing the package I got the following warning from "dpkg: directory '/usr/local/lib' not empty so not removed." (and several other similar warnings). I don't want dpkg to even _try_ to remove that directory (for obvious reasons!) how do I stop it trying to doing so?

Answer (score 1):

The other files in `/usr/bin` most certainly are no java applications.

Your jar is not an executable file on its own, it needs to be opened and executed by the `java` executable. Double clicking it will do the magic (of executing `java -jar your.jar`) in the background.

IMHO your jar doesn't belong to `/usr/bin`. `/opt/yourapp` would be wiser. See [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/122420/usr-local-or-opt).